# Comparing TimeoftheDay to a String

Tags: vb.net

Error in Comparing Time to a String

> Cdate is my previous code and i revise it to compareTime Can anyone
>   help me if the current expression to compare time is correct because
>   the message is "Contact your Administrator! Maybe your not
>   registered."

So the expression is still "false"

```
#Region "TIMER"
    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        LBLDATE.Text = My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime.Date
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        LBLTIME.Text = TimeOfDay
    End Sub
#End Region

   Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = GetConnection()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim sql1 As String
    Dim A As Integer
    Dim result = Nothing
    Dim compareTime As String = "7:01:00 PM"


    ' Dim amlate1 As String = "7:01:00 PM"
    Dim remm1 As String

    ' If CDate(Form7TO3.LBLTIME.Text) >= CDate(amlate1) Then
    If compareTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") Then
        remm1 = "LATE"
    Else
        remm1 = "ON TIME"
    End If

    Try

        sql1 = "SELECT * FROM DTR_REC WHERE MEM_CODES LIKE '" & Form7TO3.txtinput.Text & "' AND SDATE = '" & Form7TO3.LBLDATE.Text & "'"
        Dim DA As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, conn)
        Dim DS As New DataSet
        DA.Fill(DS, "dtrdb")
        A = DS.Tables("dtrdb").Rows.Count
        If A > 0 Then

            MessageBox.Show("Sorry you Already finished Log in!")

        Else
            sql = "INSERT INTO DTR_REC (MEM_CODES, AM_IN, FIRST_AM_REMARK, SDATE) VALUES (@MEM_CODES, @AM_IN, @FIRST_AM_REMARK, @SDATE)"
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@MEM_CODES", Form7TO3.txtinput.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter(" @AM_IN", Form7TO3.LBLTIME.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@FIRST_AM_REMARK", remm1))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@SDATE", DateTime.Parse(Form7TO3.LBLDATE.Text)))

            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If remm1 = "LATE" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Hurry up your Late")
            ElseIf remm1 = "ON TIME" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Very good you come on time!")
            End If
        End If

        clear()


    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim dgresult As DialogResult
        Dim ms As String
        ms = "Contact your Administrator! Maybe your not registered."
        MessageBox.Show(ms, "Error in connection", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, _
                        MessageBoxIcon.Stop, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2)

        If dgresult = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Form1.Show()
        End If

    End Try
    Return result
```

Comment: The message you say that you're seeing is displayed from a `Catch` block so an exception must be being thrown.  Have you examined that exception to see what information it contains about what went wrong?  If not, why not?  If there's an exception thrown then the very first thing you must do is look at that exception.  If you have got that information then don't keep it secret from us.  It's there to help diagnose the problem so if you want us to diagnose the problem then give us the information.  Once we know what the actual issue is, we can zero in on where to look for the cause.

Comment: i already solve the problem sir..on my first question. 
my current problem is if the records already exists, it save another record again on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current codes
Can anyone revise this codes 
If the record is already exist a messagebox will appear saying "Sorry you finished log in"

otherwise it will save/add records on my database
(The problem is , if the records still exists it add/insert another the same record)
    Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = GetConnection()
        Dim sql As String
        Dim sql1 As String
        'Dim A As Integer
        Dim result = Nothing

```
    'Dim time_1 As String = DateTime.Parse("11:00:00 PM").ToString("T")
    'Dim time_2 As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("T")
    Dim remm1 As String
    Dim PMOUT As String = "11:00:00 PM"


    Dim str As String = "HH:mm:ss"

    str = TimeOfDay()
    ' If DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > amlate1.TimeOfDay Then
    ' If DateTime.Compare(time_1, time_2) > 0 Then

    If str >= PMOUT Then
        remm1 = "LATE"
    Else
        remm1 = "ON TIME"
    End If

    Try
        conn.Open()
        sql1 = "SELECT * FROM DTR_REC WHERE MEM_CODES = '" & Form11TO7.txtinput.Text & "' AND SDATE = #" & FormatDateTime(DateTime.Now, DateFormat.GeneralDate = DateFormat.ShortDate) & "#"
        ' Dim DA As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, conn)
        Dim cmd1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql1, conn)
        'Dim DS As New DataSet
        'DA.Fill(DS, "dtrdb")
        'A = DS.Tables("dtrdb").Rows.Count
        'If A > 0 Then
        Using reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then

                'user already finished to time in
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry you Already finished Log in!")

            Else
                sql = "INSERT INTO DTR_REC (MEM_CODES, PM_IN, FIRST_PM_REMARK, SDATE) VALUES (@MEM_CODES, @PM_IN, @FIRST_PM_REMARK, @SDATE)"
                Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@MEM_CODES", Form11TO7.txtinput.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter(" @PM_IN", str))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@FIRST_PM_REMARK", remm1))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@SDATE", FormatDateTime(DateTime.Now, DateFormat.GeneralDate = DateFormat.ShortDate)))
                Dim icount As String
                icount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show(icount)
                If remm1 = "LATE" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Hurry up your Late")
                ElseIf remm1 = "ON TIME" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Very good you come on time!")
                End If
            End If
        End Using
        clear()


    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim dgresult As DialogResult
        Dim ms As String
        ms = "Contact your Administrator! Maybe your not registered."
        'MessageBox.Show(ms = "Contact your Administrator! Maybe your not registered." & vbNewLine & ex.Message)


        MessageBox.Show(ms, "Error in connection", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, _
        MessageBoxIcon.Stop, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2)

        If dgresult = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Form1.Show()
        End If
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return result
```